# Rails: how to skip validation routine on register and run it on login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, callback

I'm trying to build the backend for a subscription-only area for a website.

When the customer first pays for the subscription, he is going to be registered automatically by a callback from an external app confirming the user has paid.

I want to create the user automatically with several blank attributes. Once the user tries to login for the first time, he has to change or update all of these attributes. Then I want to run the validation routine for the attributes.

Assume the user knows his username and first password as he completes the payment.

The authentication is currently being done with Devise, but it is subject to change.

How would you go about implementing this on Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `:on => :update` after the relevant validations to bypass them on registration. Then, create a before_filter that redirects logged in users to their profile edit page throughout your application if at least one required attribute is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can just .save(false) on creation to prevent the validation completely

Not as good of a solution for your problem, but for others like me who got here through Google...

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-validations